# NODE-RED only receives UDP packets from the same machine

Tags: udp, node-red, osc

[image]A UDP node in node-red app receives successfully osc messages sent from the same computer, but fails to do so if the messages are sent from another computer on the same subnet.

Firewall you say? No firewall installed on the network or any computers. More over, the same node-red flow works fine on another computer in both scenarios.

What's interesting is the

```
sudo tcpdump -A -vv 'udp and port 3001'
```

does show the packets arriving when sent from another computer. It just they do reach the computer, but not the node-red.

Also

```
sudo nmap -sU -p 3001 192.168.1.34
```

from both another and local terminal will produce this

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.34
Host is up.
PORT     STATE         SERVICE
3001/udp open|filtered unknown
```

What are my next steps?

UPD: It seems that "Ports already in use: 3001" message confuses some commenters. This not a warning, it's a notification that the port being added uses this port.

Anyway I solved the problem by reformatting and reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Please share the exact configuration you've used for the UDP node. Without that detail its hard to suggest anything.

Comment: @knolleary -- It is a default UDP node, with a port set to 3001.Added a picture to the post

Comment: The warning in t he config window shows that something else is already bound to port 3001. You can only bind to a port once

Comment: Probably @hardillb should make of that an answer.

Comment: That message ("3001 port is bound") appears when you add a UDP node on a pristine system -- it's about the node that is being added.

Also, as I pointed in the OP, everything works if the signals are sent from local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning shown in the config window shows that there is another node already bound to port 3001.

You can only bind to a port once. If you want to run multiple flows from the same input you can wire them all to the same UDP input node.